# UnicodeEncodeError Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-unicode

I am using Tweepy for authentication and I am trying to print text, but I am unable to print the text. I am getting some UnicodeEncodeError. I tried some method but I was unable to solve it.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tweepy

consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""
access_token = ''
access_token_secret = ''

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

public_tweets = api.home_timeline()
for tweet in public_tweets:
    print tweet.text.decode("utf-8")+'\n'
```

Error:

```
(venv) C:\Users\e2sn7cy\Documents\GitHub\Tweepy>python tweepyoauth.py
Throwback to my favourite! Miss this cutie :) #AdityaRoyKapur https://t.co/sxm8g1qhEb/n
Cristiano Ronaldo: 3 hat-tricks in his last 3 matches.

Lionel Messi: 3 trophies in his last 3 matches. http://t.co/For1It4QxF/n
How to Bring the Outdoors in With Indoor Gardens http://t.co/efQjwcszDo http://t.co/1NLxSzHxlI/n
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tweepyoauth.py", line 17, in <module>
    print tweet.text.decode("utf-8")+'/n'
  File "C:\myPython\venv\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-7: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Why do you have `+'/n'`?

Comment: that wasn,t the error but thanks, i have corrected that but still i am getting the same error

Comment: I came here, and my problem was solved replacing `str(i)+"..."+str(x).encode("utf-8")` by `unicode(i)+u"..."+unicode(x).encode("utf-8")`, i.e. making everything unicode before concatenation and encoding.

Answer (score 1):

This line `print tweet.text.decode("utf-8")+'/n'` is the cause.

You decode `tweet.text` as utf-8 into an unicode string. Fine until here.

But you next try to concatenate it with a raw string '/n' (BTW, I think you really wanted `\n`) and python try to convert the unicode string to an ascii raw string giving the error.

You should concatenate with a **unicode** string to obtain a unicode string without conversion :

```
print tweet.text.decode("utf-8") + u'\n'
```

If this is not enough, it could be because your environment cannot directly print unicode strings. Then you should explictely encode it in the native charset of your system :

```
print (tweet.text.decode("utf-8") + u'\n').encode('cp850')
```

[here replace 'cp850' (*my* charset) with the charset on *your* system]

Comment: Or he can just get rid of that string all together as print will end a newline.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tweepyoauth.py", line 17, in <module>
    print tweet.text.decode("utf-8") + u'\n'
  File "C:\myPython\venv\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2026' in position 139: ordinal not in ra
nge(128)`

Comment: and I tried after removing the `\n` but still its not working

Comment: @RahulShrivastava : maybe you must explicitely encode : see my edit

Comment: how should I know charset

Comment: @RahulShrivastava : it depends on OS and local language. On a unix-like, look at environment variable `$LANG` and/or `$CHARSET`, on a Windows console, `chcp` will say it, for a Windows GUI program, it depends on system language.